# Call to thaw throwing segmentation fault

Tags: perl, segmentation-fault, freeze-thaw

I am using the
[`FreezeThaw`](https://metacpan.org/pod/FreezeThaw) module
to send serialized objects from a client to a server. It is working fine for array references with a limited number of entries, but when I do the same for a bigger array of blessed objects the server is stopping with

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Below is what I am using

Client:

```
my $message = freeze $_[1]; # encode_json
$mq->publish($channel_id, $routing_key, $message);
```

Server:

```
my $message  = $payload->{body} ;
my @got = thaw $message;
print Dumper(@got);
```

When I use the below array reference it reaches the server, but immediately after it prints, the server stops with a segmentation fault error.

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            bless( {
                     'oidptr' => bless( do{\(my $o = '140488241049968')}, 'netsnmp_oidPtr' )
                   }, 'NetSNMP::OID' ),
            '600',
            67
          ],

... approximately 200 lines repeated
```

Comment: Can you explain "_immediately after it prints_"?  At what point in the code does it crash?  From the question it seems that `thaw` worked fine ...? Also, why are you assigning to a plain array from `thaw` and why are you printing a plain array with `Dumper` (should be a reference)?

Comment: Is the server on another machine?  If so, you should use `nfreeze`.

Comment: Are the classes from which the objects are serialized (on client) and to which it is deserialized (on the server) the same, or compatible enough?

Comment: Hi, i have used Dumper just to check if the array is reaching the server. it stops after the line "print Dumper(@got);" after a successful print. the server and client are on same machine but are different programs doing different jobs.

Comment: This is way off topic, but I see lazier English every day and it's frustrating. I'm sure you're aware that ***I*** should be a *capital letter*, and you probably know that you should use *articles* like ***a***, ***an***, and ***the***? I think it's only polite to use your best English when you're asking for free help.

Comment: What is `$mq`? It's important to explain how your data us being transmitted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Freeze/thaw won't work on `NetSNMP::OID` objects.

`NetSNMP::OID` uses [XS code](https://metacpan.org/source/HARDAKER/NetSNMP-OID-5.0404/OID.xs). The XS code allocates a data structure in C, and makes the address of that data available in Perl. The only data that is stored in the Perl object, and the only data that gets saved and restores with `freeze` and `thaw`, is that address. The contents of that address will not survive across processes or across a client-server boundary on different machines.

The crash occurs because the server takes what is basically a random memory address, and tries to make sense of it as a [`netsnmp_oid_t` data structure](https://metacpan.org/source/HARDAKER/NetSNMP-OID-5.0404/OID.xs#L12).

You will have to come up with another way to access and serialize the actual contents of your `NetSNMP::OID` object.

Comment: Note that Storable provides [hooks](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Storable#Hooks) that can be used to define how to freeze and thaw objects of a class.